# Finding Laurent expansion of $\frac{2}{(2z-3)(z-5)}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Find the Laurent expansion of $\frac{2}{(2z-3)(z-5)}$ that is valid in the annulus $\frac{7}{2} < |z-5| < \infty$.  There is a lot to write out, but here is the basics of the work.

We can leave $\frac{2}{(z-5)}$ as it is.  So, we need to expand $\frac{1}{2z-3}$.  For the given annulus, I got this to equal $(\frac{1}{(z-5)})(\frac{1}{1-(\frac{-7}{2(z-5)})})$.

Using this gives us a final answer of:

$\frac{2}{(z-5)^2}-\frac{7}{(z-5)^3}+\frac{49}{(z-5)^4} - ...$

There was a lot of computation involved, which would make typing this in full way to long.  I included the important steps.  Is my solution correct?

Comment: Try first to use partial fraction decomposition, this way you have two separate terms and it will be easier to determine the Laurent expansion.

Comment: We only need to find the first 3 terms.  We never learned partial fraction decomposition for this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way, let $f(z) = \frac{2}{(2z-3)(z-5)}$, and $g(z) = f(z+5)$. Then we want to expand $f$ on the 'annulus' ${7 \over 2} < |z|$.

We have $g(z) = {1 \over z} { 1 \over z + {7 \over 2}} = {1 \over z^2} { 1 \over 1 + {7 \over 2z}}$.

Since ${ 1 \over 1 + {7 \over 2z}} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k ({7 \over 2})^k {1 \over z^k }$, for ${7 \over 2} < |z|$, you can expand to as many terms as you want.

Then you need to use $f(z) = g(z-5)$.

Comment: That's a great start! Finding the Laurent expansion is a lot easier from there!

Comment: So, it comes out that my answer is correct. But shouldn't the $\frac{7}{2}$ part be $\frac{7^k}{2^{k-1}}$ because of the 2 in the numerator of $f(z)$?

Comment: No; the computation above doesn't omit anything?

Comment: Note that $\lim_{z \to \infty} (z-5)^2 f(z) = 1$, hence your first term should be ${1 \over z-5}$.

Comment: hmmm, okay, it just seems weird that the 2 would not affect the answer at all.

Comment: I figured it out. I had a $\frac{1}{2}$ that I took out from the beginning and lost it through the computations. I now totally agree!

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{align*}\frac{2}{(2z-3)(z-5)}&=\frac{A}{2z-3}+\frac{B}{z-5}\\ 2&=A(z-5)+B(2z-3) \\ 2&=(A+2B)z-(5A+3B)\\B&=\frac{2}{7} \\ A&=-\frac{4}{7}\end{align*}$

Thus, we have (provided my arithmetic is OK)

$\begin{align*} \frac{-4}{14z-21}+\frac{2}{7(z-5)} &= \frac{-4}{14(z-5)+49}+\frac{2}{7(z-5)} \\ &= \frac{-4}{14(z-5)}\frac{1}{1-\big(\frac{-49}{14(z-5)}\big)}+\frac{2}{7(z-5)}\\&=\frac{-2}{7(z-5)}\bigg(-1+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\Big(\frac{-7}{2(z-5)}\Big)^n\bigg), |z-5|>\frac{7}{2} \\ &=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\Big(\frac{-7}{2}\Big)^{n-1}\big(z-5\big)^{-n-1}, |z-5|>\frac{7}{2}.\end{align*}$